# Read multiple values from file and assign them to specific variable for use in c++ file

Tags: c++, file-io, command-line-arguments, ifstream

I am working on a compressible solver for my advanced CFD class. I will need to run multiple simulations, so I wish to take an input from the command line which will allow me to use some scripting to run all my simulations simultaneously. I currently take the filename from the command line, and open the file to loop through each line. I do this using the following code:

```
// If input file is properly provided, try to read values from it
else
{
    std::ifstream input(input_file); // Read input file

    // Check if mesh is opened, return error otherwise
    if(input.is_open())
    {
        std::string var; // Store the variable that is being populated
        std::string val; // Store the value as a string
        // Loop through each line of the input file
        while(true)
        {
            input >> var >> val;

            // Check which variable is being populated and assign value appropriately
            // Definitely better way to do this, but if it ain't broke don't fix it
            if (var == "CFL:")
            {
                CFL = std::stod(val);
            }

            else if (var == "nx:")
            {
                nx = std::stoi(val);
            }

            else if (var == "xbegin:")
            {
                xbegin = std::stod(val);
            }

            else if (var == "xend:")
            {
                xend = std::stod(val);
            }

            else if(var == "dt:")
            {
                dt = std::stod(val);
            }

            else if (var == "gamma:")
            {
                dt = std::stod(val);
            }

            // Leave loop once end of line is reached
            if(input.eof())
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        // Close input file once we are done with it
        input.close();
    }
```

This works for the most part, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, especially if I begin having to add extra variables to be read from the input file. I would like to avoid the multiple else if statements if possible, to make adding more variables easier, and I am unsure if there is a way to do this. Thank you for the help.

Comment: `while (input >> var >> val) { ... }` is a better loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider utilizing `unordered_map`, but depending on what you want to do with the code, this might not necessarily be a better way.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string)>> key_and_action;

    // Added the function associated with the var key here
    key_and_action["nx:"] = [](std::string x)
    { std::cout << std::stoi(x) * 2 << std::endl; };

    key_and_action["CFL:"] = [](std::string x)
    { std::cout << std::stod(x) / 2 << std::endl; };

    double n;
    key_and_action["xbegin:"] = [&n](std::string x)
    { n = std::stod(x) + 0.5; };

    // If input file is properly provided, try to read values from it
    auto input_file = "example.txt";

    std::ifstream input(input_file); // Read input file

    // Check if mesh is opened, return error otherwise
    if (input.is_open())
    {
        std::string var; // Store the variable that is being populated
        std::string val; // Store the value as a string
        // Loop through each line of the input file
        while (input >> var >> val)
        {
            key_and_action[var](val); // Apply the function here
        }
    }

    std::cout << n << std::endl; // Showcase of capturing variable
    // Close input file once we are done with it
    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for avoiding `switch case` statements. It depends, as always, on the use case.

Common approaches are design patterns developed by the GOF (please see [here](https://www.gofpatterns.com/)), or jump tables, or a class hierarchies and using dynamic polymorphism, or static polymorphism using templates, or using so called associative containers.

I will show you an example code for the latter.

In C++, we could use a `std::map` or an `std::unordered_map` to associate a function with a key value. The key would be the string that identifies your fields, like "CFL:", "nx:", "xbegin:" and "xend" and so on. And the value would be some pointer or similar to your data.

Let me first add, that you do not need any of your `std:stoX` functions. The extraction operator `>>` of the input streams is already overloaded for many data types. So, you may directly use it.

Back to the map. We will use a `std::unordered_map` here. The `std::unordered_map` requires that the type of the values is the same for all entries. This will prevent solutions, where we would for example use a pointer to a class member of your data struct. In your case you have for example `int`s and `double`s. So, we need to encapsulate the reading of the values in a function that has the same signature for all your data elements.

We can achieve that by an ultra compact one liner function.

```
template <std::size_t Index>
std::istream& read(std::istream& is, Data& d) { is >> std::get<Index>(d); return is; }
```

As container for your data, I use a `std::tuple`.

- The advantage is that we can address the data elements by an index number. E.g the 2nd or the 3rd element of the struct.
- The disadvantage is that we must address the data elements by an index number. So, we do not have "speaking" names like e.g., "xbegin" or "xend".

So, what is the above function doing? The template parameter is the index in the data container, here the `tuple`. The function parameter are the `stream` from which we will read from and the instance of the `tuple`, the target variable, where we will write the data to.

This function can be assigned to a `std::function` and stored as value in the `std::unordered_map`

Now we can draft a solution example. Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std::string_literals;

// The tuple (instead of using a struct)
using Data = std::tuple<int, int, long, double>;

// Generic read for the above defined tuple
template <std::size_t Index>
std::istream& read(std::istream& is, Data& d) { is >> std::get<Index>(d); return is; }

// Test data
std::istringstream iss{ R"(int0   0
int1   1
some nonsense in the data
long   2
double   3.3)" };

// Test code
int main() {
    // Our data structure
    Data data{};

    // Map the read function to a pattern or keyword
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<std::istream& (std::istream&, Data&)>> reader{{"int0"s,read<0>},{"int1"s,read<1>},{"long"s,read<2>},{"double"s,read<3>}};

    // Read all data
    for (std::string type{}; iss >> type; reader.contains(type) and reader[type](iss,data))
        ;

    // Debug output
    std::cout << std::get<0>(data) << '\n' << std::get<1>(data) << '\n' << std::get<2>(data) << '\n' << std::get<3>(data) << '\n';
}
```

So, instead of your struct or class for storing the values, we use a `std::tuple`. Here you just store the sequence of the data types for your data members. Of course you can embed such a `tuple` also in a `class` or `struct`.

Then, we have the above described global wrapper function. This takes advantage of the stream extractors overloads for all kind of data types.

Next, you see the test data. I used for this example an `std::istringstream`, but of course you can also use any other `istream` like for example a file stream `std:ifstream`.

In main we do first define an instance of our "Data" `tuple` and call it "data". Next, we define the associative container, the `std::unordered:map` and initialize it with all keys an "read" functions.

Then, in a loop, we read all data from the `istream`. First, always the type (like "xbegin" or "xend"). After that we check, if the read string is a key, stored in the `std::unordered_map`. We use the `std::unordered_map`s `contains` function for that.

And now, a little bit hard to understand we use the boolean shortcut evaluation property of boolean expressions. The `contains` function returns `true`, if the key could be found, and false, if not. If the result is false, the the boolean "and" expressions right hand side will not be further evaluated, and with that, the "read" function will not be called.

If the key was found, then the read function for the key will be called and read the data.

Of course the right hand side of the boolean "and" condition must also be a boolean value. Therefore our "read" functions returns a reference to the `stream` with which it was called. This will allow for chaining activities, but here, most important is the fact, the `stream`s have a [bool operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). And since the "and" operator expects a `bool` on its right hand side, the `bool` operator will be used. Please note: The result of the boolean "and" expression will not be used.

Please note, that this "trick" will make the reading functionality a little bit more resilient. You can have any kind of characters in your file. It is just important, that a key word is always followed by fitting data. The result, even with nonsense in the file, will always be synchronized.

And that's it. Some subtleties in the code, but I hope that you will understand the explanation. If not, please comment and I will answer. Have fun.